# How do I set a color in the spectrum palette after initialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spectrumjs

I have a spectrum palette and a text box. The text box contains hex value of selected color and is editable. I need to be able to set a color in the palette by providing an appropriate hex value. That is, if I enter a hex value such as #000000, the pointer in the palette should point at black color. How do I achieve this?

Also, instead of hex I should also be able to get it working for R-G-B values.

How can I achieve the two cases in spectrum?

Answer (score 4):

There is [set](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/#methods-set) method, described in documentation:

> Setting the colorpicker programmatically will update the original input.

```
<input type='text' value='blanchedalmond' name='triggerSet' id='triggerSet' />
<input type='text' placeholder='Enter A Color' id='enterAColor' />
<button id='btnEnterAColor'>Trigger Set</button>

<script>
$("#triggerSet").spectrum();

// Show the original input to demonstrate the value changing when calling `set`
$("#triggerSet").show();

$("#btnEnterAColor").click(function() {
    $("#triggerSet").spectrum("set", $("#enterAColor").val());
});
</script>
```

[Here](https://code.sololearn.com/WXzv5Vawrqnn/#html) is working demo. You can enter colors names in different formats in the right field, for ex., `red`, `#000000`, `rgb(250, 250, 250)`, `rgba(1, 174, 120, 0.5)`.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried this url? i think you will get solution from this url.
https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/